# Is there a Stack Overflow Current Problems status page?

Tags: support

Subject line says it all - is there a "Current Status" page that shows known problems with the Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can check [StackStatus on Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) or the [StackStatus site](http://stackstatus.net). One of them will have information on ongoing issues with the network, scheduled maintenance, and other things. Usually the Twitter feed is your best first stop. They tend to only post to the site once they've diagnosed the problems and have extended information to outline about it.

You can also follow various Stack Exchange employees as they sometimes spit out some tidbits of information about what's going on with the network.

Comment: http://stackstatus.net/ is down ? (`http://stackstatus.net/`)

Comment: @Luuk It is up and running. It should redirect you to "www.stackstatus.net" but if you use things like HTTPS Anywhere, that may fail.

Comment: OK, it seems to be a problem of my browser ("**Microsoft Edge** Version 104.0.1293.47 (Official build) (64-bit)") 